# emsdk compilation. what flags do i needfor sucsess?

Tags: linux, compilation, emscripten, cflags, emsdk

Here are my compiler logs I don't quite understand what to do

```
$ emmake make CFLAGS="-fstack-protector-strong" LDFLAGS="-fstack-protector-strong"
```

make: make CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong LDFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong

emcc -fstack-protector-strong -fstack-protector-strong -o mkp224o.tmp main.c.o worker.c.o yaml.c.o vec.c.o cpucount.c.o base32_to.c.o base32_from.c.o base64_to.c.o base64_from.c.o ioutil.c.o keccak.c.o -lpthread -lsodium  && mv mkp224o.tmp mkp224o

wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard
wasm-ld-13: error: /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a(libsodium_la-hash_sha256_cp.o): undefined symbol: __stack_chk_guard

emcc: error: '/usr/bin/wasm-ld-13 -o mkp224o.wasm main.c.o worker.c.o yaml.c.o vec.c.o cpucount.c.o base32_to.c.o base32_from.c.o base64_to.c.o base64_from.c.o ioutil.c.o keccak.c.o /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten/libsodium.a -L/usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/lib/wasm32-emscripten -lGL -lal -lhtml5 -lstubs-debug -lnoexit -lc-debug -ldlmalloc -lcompiler_rt -lc++-noexcept -lc++abi-noexcept -lsockets -mllvm -combiner-global-alias-analysis=false -mllvm -enable-emscripten-sjlj -mllvm -disable-lsr --import-undefined --strip-debug --export-if-defined=main --export-if-defined=__start_em_asm --export-if-defined=__stop_em_asm --export-if-defined=__stdio_exit --export=emscripten_stack_get_end --export=emscripten_stack_get_free --export=emscripten_stack_get_base --export=emscripten_stack_init --export=stackSave --export=stackRestore --export=stackAlloc --export=__wasm_call_ctors --export=__errno_location --export=malloc --export=free --export=emscripten_main_thread_process_queued_calls --export-table -z stack-size=5242880 --initial-memory=16777216 --no-entry --max-memory=16777216 --global-base=1024' failed (returned 1)
make: *** [GNUmakefile:99: mkp224o] Error 1
emmake: error: 'make CFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong LDFLAGS=-fstack-protector-strong' failed (returned 2)

Comment: I do not know the answer but this does not look correct for a linker flag: **LDFLAGS="-fstack-protector-strong"**

Comment: I try without it, but the result is the same

Comment: I did not say remove it, I provided a suggestion that it is incorrect. Lookup the correct linker options/flags.

Comment: Oh, very thanlk you for answering. I solved a problem but not clearly understand on which step it was fixed. Now i will write  "what i was doing" in the answer...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, but I did not track at what step it was done, since I walked in circles many times.

From the moment it didn't work for me, I did:

-installed bison and gawk

```
sudo apt install bison gawk
```

-copied the "c++" folder from the Include folder to the /usr/share/emscripten/cache/sysroot/include directory.

- switched to providing python, with the commands:

  python3 '/usr/share/emscripten/emconfigure.py' ./configure --prefix="$(pwd)/install"

  python3 '/usr/share/emscripten/emmake.py' make clean

  python3 '/usr/share/emscripten/emmake.py' make
- when code errors occur, set

  sudo apt install python3-pysodium
- after I solved a couple of compilation errors (from a very long list of errors) and corrected by type in terminal:

  emcc -Wall -Wno-error -Wextra -Wno-unused-function -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -x c++ -g -O2 -lm -ldl -Wall -Wpointer-arith -finline-functions -ffast-math -DED25519_donna -fPIE  -DSTATISTICS -DPASSPHRASE -DVERSION='"unknown"' -D'CRYPTO_NAMESPACETOP=crypto_sign_ed25519_donna' -D'_CRYPTO_NAMESPACETOP=*crypto_sign_ed25519_donna' -D'CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(name)=crypto_sign_ed25519_donna*##name' -D'_CRYPTO_NAMESPACE(name)=*crypto_sign_ed25519_donna* ##name' -c -o main.c.o.tmp main.c && mv main.c.o.tmp main.c.o

and then finished compiling

```
 python3 '/usr/share/emscripten/emmake.py' make
```